# Can't connection with socket server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to connection to socket server on port 8080 but keep getting this error `Connection to IPAddress:8080 timed out!`
this my server code

```
const express = require("express");
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io');
const socket = io(http);
http.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

how to solve it please ?

Comment: Change the port probably and try out?

Comment: @susenj tried it but still have the problem :")

Answer (score 0):

You have to write more code of socket you can not connect to socket direct
You have to write connection function

Follow This [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_hello_world.htm) to know basics of socket

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var port =  8080; // set our port

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    // Everytime a client logs in, display a connected message
    console.log("Server-Client Connected!");

   socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('A user disconnected');
   });
});

http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port); // shoutout to the user
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello world</title>
   </head>
   <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   
   <script>
      var socket = io();
   </script>
   <body>Hello world</body>
</html>
```

after running server check `localhost:8080`

Comment: this is just the main section of code
there is another sections have the code you write
the main problem that the socket is working perfectly on my computer but on the server getting timed out